# Flag on condition

Tags: sql, vertica

Here's my table :

```
key date
a   2002
a   2014
a   2011
b   2004
b   2016
b   2001
```

I'd like a `SELECT` statement that adds a flag for the most recent date, like that :

```
key date flag
a   2002 0
a   2014 1
a   2011 0
b   2004 0
b   2016 1
b   2001 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your current query attempt?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [analytical function](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/MAXAnalytic.htm) if you don't want to do a group by or self-join.  You can probably consolidate this a little if you want to, but I find splitting it out using `with` makes it more obvious what is going on.

```
with max_date_query as (
    select key, date, max(date) over (partition by key) max_date
    from mytable
)
select key, date, case when date = max_date then 1 else 0 end flag
from max_date_query
```

There are other variations on the same theme where you can order the window by `date desc` and use `row_number()` instead of `max()` to determine the flag. I would imagine the one I showed is better, but not sure how much it will really make a difference.  You might need to use that method if you have cases where you have duplicate max dates and need to really only choose one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, case when t2.a is null 
                  then 0
                  else 1  
             end as flag
from your_table t1
left join 
(
   select key, max(date) as mdate
   from your_table
   group by key
) t2 on t1.key = t2.key and t1.date = t2.mdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the "most recent" condition is (last "X" years?) and assuming the "2015" are in fact DATE values (not char), try:

```
select 
t1.key,
t1.date,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF('year', t1.date, CURRENT_DATE) < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as flag
from table t1;
```

if the "date" in fact is an integer:

```
select 
t1.key,
t1.date,
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - t1.date < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as flag
from table t1;
```

Hope it helps
Sérgio